# Custom Dimensions with Goal Conversation Rate

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking, goals, custom-dimensions

I have following flow for one of my booking module.
Select Store -> Fill Appointment Form -> Appointment Confirmation

I have created Goals for this which is working perfectly. Here I want report which indicates store wise Goal Conversation rate.
I have created custom dimensions(Store Name) for getting store name which I am sending with each pageview.

When I tried to generate report of 'Store Name' to Goal Conversation rate, it is not showing any data.

Any clue how can we achieve this?

Comment: Same question. Any update?